# Weighted/Directional Graph and associated Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, adjacency-matrix

[This is a question from Intellipath, a program my school uses to teach lessons...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rdSk.png)

I apologize if this is a type of redundant question, but my question has to do with the graph specifically. I understand weighted and directional graphs just fine, I also understand adjacency matrixes just fine. However, according to my instructor and this program, I am wrong in this case, but I don't see it. I believe that Towns(4,1) = 12, and the opposite (1,4) is -12, 0, or the infinite symbol (don't know how to type it). Either way, (4,1) is equal to 12, that is the important one. My instructor is telling me that (4,1) is -12 and I do not understand where he is getting that. He has asked other collegues of his and they supposedly agree, but again, I don't see it. I have asked many friends of mine, googled other examples and have reached out to other sites, and I have yet to find someone who disagrees with me, but I figured I would try here as well. So, IF somehow, (4,1) = -12, please explain that to me....thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is purely a matter of convention: it is clear that, in words, *the distance from $D$ to $A$ is $12$*. We all agree on this. The question is: how do you represent this information as an entry of the adjacency matrix? Do you represent the distance from $D$ to $A$ as $T(4,1)$ or as $T(1,4)$? It's a matter of convention, but the more intuitive option would be to use $T(4,1)$ here, which means that you are right.

Concerning the minus sign, it's again a matter of convention: given that there is no arrow pointing from $A$ to $D$, I interpret this as saying that you cannot go directly from $A$ to $D$, which symbolically means that the distance from $A$ to $D$ is $\infty$, i.e. (using the convention chosen in the above paragraph), $T(1,4) = \infty$. The problem is that there is no way to place such an abstract symbol as $\infty$ in a computer program, therefore it is better to represent it as negative values: every negative entry should be read as meaning the absence of an oriented edge between the corresponding vertices. Using $0$ to encode this absence is not a good idea: sometimes $0$ is used on the diagonal of the matrix, representing the fact that one may go from any town $X$ into $X$ at no cost at all (but, again, this is yet another convention).

As you see, everything depends on conventions, and one cannot give a more detailed answer without knowing which ones your instructor uses. In any case, if your instructor uses "the other" convention regarding the order of the indices (i.e. $T(1,4)$ instead of $T(4,1)$), you shouldn't worry too much, because his matrix will be the transposed of yours, and all the significant theorems about oriented graphs do not "feel" this transposition (i.e. they remain true and give the same results with and without transposition).

Comment: Thank you for the response! So, about your first paragraph...both T(4,1) and T(1,4) are already represented in the matrix, from my understanding. If you look at my comment on Laars' post you'll see what I mean. Basically, the top right cell represents (1,4) and the bottom left is (4,1), as I understand. Every example I can find (including others in this class) read and input values this way. Just FYI, this isn't necessarily governed by my instructor, the program Intellipath presents a lesson, and then you take a quiz....

Comment: And there is one piece of the question I left out (on purpose), but this might help shed some light on the convention the question is trying to get at. This is a multiple choice question, you don't actually have to fill in the table. It basically wants you to choose which is more true out of the following options: A) T(4,4) = -1 B) T(4,1) = 12 C) T(3,4) = 0 D) T(1,1) = 1....I chose B and was told I was wrong. However, if you look at all the answers, both B and C are correct, no? But again, my instructor does not believe B is correct...he says (4,1) = -12 and I don't see how...

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: I would choose (B) too. In order to decide what an entry of $0$ means, I would have to know what convention Intellisense uses - which I don't. As I've written above, $0$ usually means that there is "no distance" between towns, while $\infty$ means that there's no direct route between towns. This means that with the convention that *I* use, $T(3,4) = \infty$, because there's no edge from $C$ to $D$. On the other hand, $T(1,1) = T(2,2) = T(3,3) = T(4,4) = 0$, because the distance between a town and itself is, obviously, $0$.

Comment: Agreed....thank you much for your input!

Comment: A friend of mine, who is a math genius...said this: "I think you are using knowledge the question doesnt need to answer. That question only cares about adjacency. Not weight. Not direction. It says build an adjacency matrix. The only answers possible are 1 or zero. The weights and directions are there as extraneous information.

I almost guarentee it.

First that makes C correct and nothing else. Second that question only uses the words adjacency. Not weight. Not direction."

Comment: If that is the mindset of the question...makes sense...but then it is an unfair question, because the graph presented IS weighted and directional, so why would it expect you to not factor that in? I've emailed my instructor with the information I got from my friend and you as well, we shall see what he thinks...

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: Your friend would be right if you had an unlabeled graph: in that case the adjacency matrix would contain only $1$s and $0$s. When edges carry labels, though, such as "miles" in your example, things change a bit as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are interpreting what each cell in your table represents.

The cell that represents going from D to A should be 12 and the cell that represents going from A to D should be -12, based on the digraph presented and assuming that traveling against the direction is interpreted as negative.

You and your instructor have to be clear on which cells represents which travels.

Comment: Agreed...but as I understand it, Adjacency tables are read "left to right", meaning, you start at the top of the left column and move across the top column, left to right, then move down a row on the left, and repeat...therefor, the top right cell is "A to D" and the bottom left cell is "D to A"...this is what I have gathered from my text book and multiple online sources. Given this information, it is my understanding that I am correct in saying "D to A is 12"...what do you think?